# 12 V regulator from 13+ V

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, dc

I have a fairly good understanding of electronics, but I wanted to check that my solution to the following issue is correct.

I have a travel trailer with a lithium battery bank (voltages range from 12.7 V to 13.3 V)

The battery bank is hooked up to the fusebox that supplies DC power to some electronics in the trailer.

I want to install a new exhaust fan for our toilet, and the small fan runs at 12 V, 0.05 A.

When I hook it up directly to the fuse box it doesn't work, but when I run a lower voltage, closer to 12 V, it seems to work.

My question is, do I need to put a 12 V voltage regulator between the power and the fan?

Something like [this L7812ABV](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/L7812ABV/585970)?

Comment: It seems odd that a 12V fan would not run at 13V, but perhaps that’s the case.  ‘7812’-style regulators tend to have a high dropout voltage (a few volts) which means they require a somewhat higher input voltage before they can achieve 12V out, so you may find that you’re getting 10 or 11V if your battery isn’t fully charged.  The part you’ve identified has a dropout of 2V.  This may be ok for your application, but you might be better off just using a diode that will give you a drop of around 600mV (or use two or three in series if needed).  If you look around you may find a linear or…

Comment: …switch-mode regulator with a lower dropout voltage.  Also note that linear regulators aren’t very efficient, so you might need a fairly substantial heatsink.  1A load (guessing) with a 2V drop means 2W to dissipate which isn’t too bad but too much to dispense with a heatsink altogether.

Comment: Check the datasheet. The vast majority of fans will run happily with 13.3 V as is.

Comment: Please test this fan with another 13.5 V supply before you add a regulator or series diodes.

Answer (score 5):

It is very strange that the fan would care about a small difference like that. Maybe check again and measure the actual voltage on the fan wires.

The 7812 will have about 1.5V (minimum) drop so you'll get maybe 11V to 12V depending on the input voltage. It will limit the fan voltage to 12V+/-5%. It may not be reliable connected to a vehicle electrical system directly.